how to use Fill solid function to stay on after the other patterns have ran?
I would like the LEDs to stay on solid after the last LED has returned to the beginning of the led strip to start the sequence again. Hopefully my code loads up correctly.
[from the comment:] "return to the begin of the strip of Leds" means, LED0 to LED40 back to the beginning, which would be LED0 starting the pattern again.
My current code:
#include <FastLED.h>

#define NUM_LEDS 40
#define LED_PIN 4

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  FastLED.setBrightness(20); //0-255 brightness
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    leds[i] = CRGB::GhostWhite;
    FastLED.show();
    delay(75);
    leds[i] = CRGB::Black;
    for (int i = NUM_LEDS - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      leds[i] = CRGB::Black;
      FastLED.show();
      delay(65);
      leds[i] = CRGB::GhostWhite;
      fill_solid(leds, NUM_LEDS, CRGB::GhostWhite);
    }
  }
}


what does this mean? ... after the last led has returned to the beginning ... beginning of what?

full code is up Now  , return to the begin of the strip of Leds ,0-40 back to the beginning  which would be led0 starting the pattern again.

I have formatted your source. Please check it as see if it is what you intended. Currently, it is not compilable because of a missing closing parenthesis at the call of fill_solid(). You might have just a simple typo or logic error.

Oh, and if you have new or additional information, please put it into your question. For your other comment, I did this already.

it makes no sense to have a for block inside another for block ... what are you trying to accomplish?

Maybe it would help to show what each frame of the animation cycle should look like with a small number of LEDs. However many LEDs is enough to make the pattern clear and not so many that you can't easily draw all frames. Perhaps 4 LEDs for illustration purposes.

@jsotola What I’m trying to accomplish is for my lights, at power up that my led strip will light up one after the other from led0 to led40 and back to led0 but on the return to led0 I would like to light the entire strip or addressable leds to stay on till I shut them off.
